# Moving UL/LI elements using CSS3 animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create some animations by using CSS3 transitions.
Imagine the following UL/LI element:

```
<ul>
    <li class="green" id="green" style="display: none;">Contents 1</li>
    <li class="red" id="red" style="display: none;">Contents 2</li>
    <li class="yellow" id="yellow" style="display: none;">Contents 3</li>
</ul>
```

It's important to know that those elements are positioned horizontally next to eachother (display: inline-block).

Now, when I click on a button, I show those elements, that isn't an issue.
This is done with the following HTML code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#green').show();">Make contents 1 visible</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#red').show();">Make contents 2 visible</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#yellow').show();">Make contents 3 visible</a>
```

When I want to put an animation on it, I can do it by adding a certain class to the element and the CSS would like this:

```
.animate { transition: all linear 5s; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; }
```

But now, let's mark the LI elements as absolute, so they are all displayed at the same location.

What I would like to have now as an animation is the following:

- When I enabled item 2 it just fades in.
- When I then enable item 1, it fades in, and at the same time, item 2 should start moving to the right until item 1 has taken up all the required space it needs.

But, to make it difficult, neither of the items has a fixed with, because the content of the UL LI elements is dynamiccly.

Here's a fiddle to better understand it:

http://jsfiddle.net/dw4Lz8qe/

So, I would like to fade an item is, but if there's already an item visible, the visible item(s) should start moving to the right until the required space for the fading in element is fully taken.

So, I do hope that this question was clear.

Kind regards,

Comment: If you add `position: relative;` to your `.animate` class it starts you on the right track. As for animating the slide effect look into [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Do I really need Jquery? Isn't it possible using css3 animations?

Comment: You could probably get away with CSS3 however you're already using jQuery. Either way maybe [CSS3 Keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) can help.

Comment: No. I'm not using Jquery. I'm using angular in my app but the fiddle was quickly created with Jquery. How should I solve it with key frames since I don't know the width of the fading in element, meaning that I don't know at whixh left coordinate I should set the element.

Comment: Angular uses jQuery, and even if not implemented by you, it uses it's own lite version of jQuery.
As for non-fixed widths, you can't animate to an unknown width. If the `li` isn't loaded dynamically you can still calculate the width while hidden and apply it to your css.

Answer (score 2):

Animating `font-size` may solve your problem:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block; 
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.green {background-color: green;}
.red {background-color: red;}
.yellow {background-color: yellow;}

.animate {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('#green').toggleClass('animate') ">Toggle contents 1</button>
<button onclick="$('#red').toggleClass('animate')   ">Toggle contents 2</button>
<button onclick="$('#yellow').toggleClass('animate')">Toggle contents 3</button>

<ul class="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
  <li class="green" id="green">Contents 1</li>
  <li class="red" id="red">Contents 2</li>
  <li class="yellow" id="yellow">Contents 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very good approach, but unfortunately, it introduces some behaviour which I don't like.

Comment: Thank you - this solved an issue that I had (I want to achieve the exact functionality your solution provides).

Answer (score 1):

As long as your `<li>` can have a fixed with, it works with css. Check your updated fiddle - you might want to use that to dive deeper into the matter. Problem is, you cannot transition between `width: 0` and `width: auto`as this is not supported by any browser I know of.

http://jsfiddle.net/dw4Lz8qe/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, I don't have a width since the content is dynamic. I do think I need to use jQuery.

Comment: As long as you have a defined height, you might go with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dw4Lz8qe/18/